# Which power source/elements are better for a spot welder?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm going to build a spot welder for the batteries of my RC models, but started thinking which power source is the better choise:

1. 12V car battery with higher start current (500A+)
2. Transformer which is usually a lot more expensive, and need expensive additional elements to be used for spot welding

I'm assuming that during welding the car battery variant is good to be disconnected from the power grid (not connected to the charger) during welding and also there's a need for momentary switch for high current (50A+ or more) plus a starter relay 12V alos rated for at least 500A

Comment: i'd go with the car battery .... easy to charge (hook up to your car to charge) ...... used ones are easy to get and and are cheap  ....... some sort of current limiting may be needed

Comment: Well, what type/scheme of current limiting you offer?